# Preventing the browser from reloading the page when a user hits Back

Tags: html, browser, reload, back-button

I seem to have the opposite problem from most SO users. I have a static page that changes rarely, and I want the browser not to reload that page when the user navigates back to it quickly. I have not been able to find any simple list of rules that detail when a browser reloads on back-navigation, and when it does not.

If it makes a difference, my URL has a query string, and is served using the `https://` protocol.

Comment: Why only on back navigation? What if the user loads this page from history, and it's not updated? It shouldn't be reloaded as well. HTTP 304 not modified status code is what you need: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

Comment: This is just something I am less concerned with. I am OK only solving the back-navigation case, because many users click a link, then go back quickly if they don't find what they need. Having an extra server load at that point is the problem I want to address.

Comment: Are you using a php script and want to send HTTP 304 not modified?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm doing, nor what I want to do.

Comment: If you have a static html page, then the situation is simplified. Apache must send HTTP 304 header automatically. Can you give a link to a test page, looking exactly like you use?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to know if the back button has been used.  Just tell the browser to cache your page by using cache control headers.  You will see lots of examples from Google - [http cache control headers](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_rn=8&gs_ri=psy-ab&gs_mss=http%20cache%20control%20he&tok=mTh_JwPRTIxhjT9GA3Nzww&pq=http%20cache%20control&cp=26&gs_id=bj&xhr=t&q=http+cache+control+headers&es_nrs=true&pf=p&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&oq=http+cache+control+headers&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.eWU&fp=af0ef477335b7efa&biw=1342&bih=974)

Specifically, look at these meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="..." />
<meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="..." />
```

**Edit:**

Here is a link to one of the results from that Google search. I think it gives a pretty good explanation of how these headers work.  [Increasing Application Performance with HTTP Cache Headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers)

With these headers you can specify how long to cache your pages; 10 minutes, 30 minutes, hours, days, etc.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is a resource which will list for how different browsers honor these headers under different circumstances. For example, I recall URLs with a query string being handled differently from ones without by some browser in the past.

Comment: That is why I included that Google link for you.  There is a HUGE amount of information on the web about this.  I added one of the resources from that search to my answer for you.  It explains this pretty well and gives examples.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **onpageshow** event of the body tag ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function caller()
    {
      return false;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onpageshow="caller();">
</body>
```

**Works on most cases.**